# custom error messages for invalid form – js script uncaught typeError

Tags: javascript, forms, addeventlistener

I'm a newbie with javascript and have adapted a script from github to customise error messages on a 5-field form.

It worked in its original 3-field format, but now gets stuck with the error message:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') at form.js:20:19`

I've followed a lot of advice on here, re. the script not waiting for the page to load (moving the script to just above the  tag, moving the script to an external file, putting the link at the bottom of the page, adding async to the link), but nothing seems to work.

This is the script (I'm content that the html and field names are accurate):

```
const nameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]');
const emailInput = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
const categoryInput = document.querySelector('input[name="category"]');
const messageInput = document.querySelector('input[name="message"]');
const privacyInput = document.querySelector('input[name="privacy"]');
const allInputs = [nameInput, emailInput, categoryInput, messageInput, privacyInput];


nameInput.addEventListener('invalid', function (event) {
  if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Remember to let us know your name');
    }
})

emailInput.addEventListener('invalid', function (event) {
  if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Remember to input a valid email address');
    }
})

categoryInput.addEventListener('invalid', function (event) {
  if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Remember to let us know what category your message falls into');
    }
})

messageInput.addEventListener('invalid', function (event) {
  if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Remember to ask your question');
    }
})
      
privacyInput.addEventListener('invalid', function (event) {
  if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('Remember to confirm you are happy with our privacy policy');
    }
})      

allInputs.forEach(function (input) {
  input.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    event.target.setCustomValidity('');
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem with this is it does not matter where you put your script tag in the file I will still recommand you to use a 'DOMContentLoaded' so the problem with this is that one of the `querySelector` calls is not finding the specified element, resulting in a null value. When trying to access the `addEventListener` property on null, it leads to the mentioned error.

now as for what you can do is assuming you have your html as this

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  const nameInput = document.querySelector('input[name="name"]');
  const emailInput = document.querySelector('input[name="email"]');
  const categoryInput = document.querySelector('input[name="category"]');
  const messageInput = document.querySelector('input[name="message"]');
  const privacyInput = document.querySelector('input[name="privacy"]');
  const allInputs = [
    nameInput,
    emailInput,
    categoryInput,
    messageInput,
    privacyInput,
  ];

  nameInput.addEventListener("invalid", function (event) {
    if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
      event.target.setCustomValidity("Remember to let us know your name");
    }
  });

  emailInput.addEventListener("invalid", function (event) {
    if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
      event.target.setCustomValidity("Remember to input a valid email address");
    }
  });

  categoryInput.addEventListener("invalid", function (event) {
    if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
      event.target.setCustomValidity(
        "Remember to let us know what category your message falls into"
      );
    }
  });

  messageInput.addEventListener("invalid", function (event) {
    if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
      event.target.setCustomValidity("Remember to ask your question");
    }
  });

  privacyInput.addEventListener("invalid", function (event) {
    if (event.target.validity.valueMissing) {
      event.target.setCustomValidity(
        "Remember to confirm you are happy with our privacy policy"
      );
    }
  });

  allInputs.forEach(function (input) {
    input.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
      event.target.setCustomValidity("");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="myForm">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name" required />

      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" required />

      <label for="category">Category:</label>
      <input type="text" name="category" required />

      <label for="message">Message:</label>
      <input type="text" name="message" required />

      <label for="privacy">
        <input type="checkbox" name="privacy" required />
        I agree to the privacy policy
      </label>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

the trick is to check for if the dom is completely loaded or not
wrap the whole content of that script inside a

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {});
```

let me know if you need any questions regarding this

Comment: Thank you, this has got rid of the addEventListener error-message, and my custom invalid-field messages are now showing up when tested, but even if all fields are then correctly completed, the first invalid-field message remains, and the form won't send.

Comment: what is the error message that is showing in there and for form submission form submission is happening , see the page is reloading it means that the form is submitting successfully , now you have to handle where and what kind of data you are sending through the form.

Comment: I just keep getting the same error as before:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>   

It appears under inspect element > console.  

The script appears to work – it will show my custom messages when I leave a field blank, but it sticks on that first blank field, continues to show the "please complete this field" message (even if I've subsequently entered valid text) and the form won't send.